# Работа с TWebBrowser в Delphi [закрыт]

Tags: delphi

Меня интересует следующее:

1. Как узнать, что страница загрузилась полностью?
2. Я знаю, что нужная мне картинка хранится в `webBrowser1.OleObject.Document.Images.item(i)`. Как мне её вставить в `Image.Picture` независимо от расширения картинки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Наступает событие `WebBrowser1DocumentComplete`
2. Сохраняйте ее в файл и загружайте в `Image` уже из файла.

А чтобы не быть зависимым от расширения файла, допишите в `USES` jpeg (для jpg) Acpng (для png).

Comment: как сохранить в файл?
буду очень признателен за кусочек кода (:

Answer (score 0):

```
var body, imgs, controlRange: olevariant;

body := WebBrowser1.OleObject.document.body;
imgs := WebBrowser1.OleObject.document.images.item(i);//нужный img
controlRange := body.createControlRange;
controlRange.add(imgs);
controlRange.execCommand('Copy', False, EmptyParam);//копируем
Image1.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromClipboardFormat(cf_Bitmap, ClipBoard.GetAsHandle(cf_Bitmap), 0);

{!!!самое главное, без чего не работало, добавить в конце всей программы}

initialization
 OleInitialize(nil);

finalization
 OleUninitialize;
```

Comment: В редакторе есть кнопка "101010" для подсветки кода